# Split Imported Vendor files into a vendor bundle

Tags: javascript, webpack

With Webpack, there is support for code splitting to different bundles.  One of the options is to specify a set of modules you would like to choose as a split point.

Taken from [here](https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html):

```html
var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: "./app.js",
    vendor: ["jquery", "underscore", ...],
  },
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin(/* chunkName= */"vendor", /* filename= */"vendor.bundle.js")
  ]
};
```

This shows how to split out modules like `jquery`.  However for some javascript libraries that aren't in node_modules that may exist in a more traditional setup like:

`/src
/lib
  /vendor
    /fooLibrary
      fooLibrary.js
      fooLibrary.css`

What I would like is to move these files into the vendor bundle but cannot work out how to specify these files in the vendor entry point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set abs path to vendor lib

```
var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: "./server.js",
    vendor: ["/mylib/"],
  },
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin(/* chunkName= */"vendor", /* filename= */"vendor.bundle.js")
  ]
};
```

and webpack build lib from abs path to vendor bundle.

[image]

But import worked only if index.js exist, so before you should rename vendor file module to index.js with webpack copy plugin or use any tasks script for instance gulp task.